# c++ std::bind keeping object alive

Tags: c++, c++11

Here is the code, it's pretty straightforward.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<"Foo::print\n";
    }
}; 


Game::Game()
{
    {
        Foo foo;
        player.onclick = bind(&Foo::print,foo);

    }
    player.onclick();
}
```

After the inner scope is done the foo object goes out of scope, but the print method is still called, I guess this happens because player holds a reference to the foo object? Is there a way to stop this from happening? I don't want objects to stay alive and receive events when they are supposed to be destroyed.

Thanks.

Comment: that code is not straightforward. where is the rest?

Comment: What else do you need? bind is the std::tr1::bind.
onclick is a simple function like this 

std::function<void()> onclick;
Removed the unnecessary player stuff too.

Comment: so you use tr1::bind. In that case, I need includes, main, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are binding to a copy of `foo`; that copy lasts as long as the bound function object, while the original `foo` is destroyed at the end of its scope.

If you don't want to keep it alive, then bind to a pointer (`&foo`) or a reference (`std::ref(foo)`); and then you must be careful not to call the function object once `foo` has gone out of scope. Note that there's no way to tell from the function object that this has happened; calling it will give undefined behaviour.

In order to safely disconnect the object when it's destroyed, you would have to either arrange for its destructor to reassign `onclick`, or make some other object responsible for first reassigning `onclick`, and then destroying the object.

Comment: Ok, so I changed the bind to this :
    Foo foo;
    player.onclick = bind(&Foo::print,&foo);

And the print method is still getting called, wasn't what I was expecting.

Comment: @BlackKnight: Yes, the function object will still be callable, but calling it after `foo` is destroyed will give undefined behaviour (In this case, that behaviour is likely to print the message, since the member function doesn't do anything with the dead object). If you need the function object to be safely invalidated, then you'll need to do that yourself somehow.

Comment: Only way I can see handling that is making a Foo destructor and setting a zombie flag, and then returning from the handlers immediately if the object is dead.
Is there a way to break the binding between player.onclick and Foo.print?

Comment: @BlackKnight : If the object is destroyed, checking a zombie flag won't help -- you're still in UB-land.

Comment: @BlackKnight: The only way to break the binding is to reassign `onclick`. The zombie flag won't work, since it will be destroyed along with the object. If you really want automatic invalidation, then you'll have to find a way to reassign `onclick` from the object's destructor. A better solution might be to make some other object responsible for both destroying the object and disconnecting it from whatever it's been connected to.

Comment: @BlackKnight, you can actually create some sort of smart pointer, that will be wrapped around actual `Foo` class, and in destructor of `Foo`, you can say to this container to set "zombie flag"

Comment: The following seems to work :
`
    class Foo
    {
public:
 Foo(Player& player):player(player)
 {
  player.onclick = bind(&Foo::print,this);
 }
 ~Foo()
 {
  player.onclick = NULL;
 }

 void print()
 {
  std::cout<<"Foo::print\n";
 }
private:
 Player& player;
};


Game::Game() 
{
 
 {
  Foo foo(player);
  
  if(player.onclick)
   player.onclick();

 }
 
 if(player.onclick)
  player.onclick();


}`

Comment: @BlackKnight, the problem is that you can bind now only against `onclik` signal of `player`-class object. If this restriction is ok, this solution should work

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you actually want an event loop. While `std::bind` is useful for something like that it isn't one all by itself. I suggest you have a look at [boost.signals](http://www.boost.org/libs/signals/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `shared_ptr` when you assign `Foo` to `Player`, and keep a `weak_ptr` to `Foo` in `Player`. Then try to lock the `weak_ptr` in the `onclick` function to see if `Foo` is still alive. Something like this:

```
using namespace std;
class Foo
{
    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout<<"Foo::print\n";
        }
}; 

class Player
{
    public:
        weak_ptr<function<void()>> _onClickFuntion;
        void onclick()
        {
            shared_ptr<function<void()>> tempFunction(_onClickFunction.lock());
            if (tempFunction)
                tempFunction();
        }
}

Game::Game()
{
    {
        Foo foo;
        player._onClickFuntion = shared_ptr<function<void()>>(new bind(&Foo::print,foo));
    }
    player.onclick();
}
```